# Is it necessary to mark functions with the `inline(never)` attribute that are responsible for eliminating generic overhead?

Tags: rust, attributes, inline, compiler-optimization

Is this enough to prevent generic overhead at the cost of calling a function? Or is it necessary to specify `#[inline(never)]`?

```
fn foo<T: Add<i32>>(a: i32, b: T) -> i32 {
    fn static_ops(a: i32) -> i32 {
        a += 99;
        if a % 100 == 0 {
            println!("Static output{a}");
        }
        a *= a;
        a
    }

    a = static_ops(a);
    b + a
}
```

And will this code have the same requirements?

```
fn foo<T: Add<i32>>(a: i32, b: T) -> i32 {
    let static_ops = |a: i32| -> i32 {
        a += 99;
        if a % 100 == 0 {
            println!("Static output{a}");
        }
        a *= a;
        a
    }

    a = static_ops(a);
    b + a
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not just it is necessary to not use `#[inline(never)]`, using it is a mistake. You don't want the compiler to not inline the function, it'll dismiss optimization opportunities.

However, reconsider separating the function. It reduces readability. Do it only if your function is used many times.

Comment: I didn't want runtime optimization. I wanted to optimize binary size, so why is using inline(never) an error? And I don’t think that in my case it is necessary to separate the functions, because the function is small. If I do it differently, it will occupy an external namespace, but here it is encapsulated. I just thought that the compiler might think that since a function is called in one place, it needs to be inline, and this would produce generic overhead

Comment: @Empty Sometimes inlining can improve binary size too. Let LLVM decide. Do allow inlining, but optimize for size with `opt-level=s` or `opt-level=z`.

Comment: @Empty And don't try to second-guess the compiler. Odds are it'll be much better than you at removing overhead.

Comment: @Empty This technique *can* be useful (my guess is especially if using `opt-level=z`) to help the compiler across translation units can see that inner function is common and can be its own function. But still `#[inline(never)]` is rarely a good idea: tell the compiler what you want through flags and let it work out the details.

Comment: Okay, I'll set the flag opt-level = 3 (maximum). What if `fn static_ops` is very large? The compiler will inline it. Because the flag configures how to optimize absolutely everything. What if I want the rest of the code to be optimized as much as possible, but this weak spot is not optimized? Then why am I wrong and can’t use `inline(never)`?

Comment: "What if fn static_ops is very large? The compiler will inline it" - when the function actually _is_ very large, it likely will not, since inlining large function is often a pessimisation due to increasing instruction cache misses.

Comment: Of course, if you've actually checked, and the compiler _did_ inline the function, you might want to add `#[inline(never)]` and benchmark both cases. There's no silver bullet, after all. It's just that in _most_ cases this is not necessary.

Comment: Great, I was waiting for a comment about instruction cache. With this in my head, I now understood everything. But for some reason the site stopped responding to the request to make this answer a solution( The response's activity history shows that I'm trying to mark it as a solution, but it's red